# Are the lists divisible?

Tags: code-golf, math, array, decision-problem

*Inspired (with the explanation stolen from) [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45906747/7742131)*

### Background

Say you have two lists `A = [a_1, a_2, ..., a_n]` and `B = [b_1, b_2, ..., b_n]` of integers. We say `A` is **potentially-divisible** by `B` if there is a permutation of `B` that makes `a_i` divisible by `b_i` for all `i`. The problem is then: is it possible to reorder (i.e. permute) `B` so that `a_i` is divisible by `b_i` for all `i`?
For example, if you have

```
A = [6, 12, 8]
B = [3, 4, 6]
```

Then the answer would be `True`, as `B` can be reordered to be `B = [3, 6, 4]` and then we would have that `a_1 / b_1 = 2`, `a_2 / b_2 = 2`, and `a_3 / b_3 = 2`, all of which are integers, so `A` is potentially-divisible by `B`.

As an example which should output `False`, we could have:

```
A = [10, 12, 6, 5, 21, 25]
B = [2, 7, 5, 3, 12, 3]
```

The reason this is `False` is that we can't reorder `B` as 25 and 5 are in `A`, but the only divisor in `B` would be 5, so one would be left out.

### Your task

Your task is, obviously, to determine whether two lists (given as input) are potentially divisible. You may take input in any accepted manner, as with output.

Duplicates in the lists are a possibility, and the only size restrictions on the integers are your language. All integers in both lists will be larger than 0, and both lists will be of equal size.

As with all [decision-problem](/questions/tagged/decision-problem)s the output values must be 2 distinct values that represent true and false.

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest code wins!

### Test cases

```
Input, input => output

[6, 12, 8], [3, 4, 6] => True
[10, 5, 7], [1, 5, 100] => False
[14, 10053, 6, 9] [1,1,1,1] => True
[12] [7] => False
[0, 6, 19, 1, 3] [2, 3, 4, 5, 6] => undefined
```

Comment: @Shaggy from the question: *both lists will be of equal size*

Comment: Why is the last test case undefined?

Comment: @Dennis one of the lists has a 0 in it

Comment: Right. (Not sure why, **0** is divisible by all integers.) Do the two outputs have to be truthy and falsy, or just consistent?

Comment: @Dennis 1) it's in case 0 is in the second list, to avoid 0 division errors 2) just consistent

Answer (score 10):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>7</s> <s>6</s> 5 bytes

Saved 2 bytes thanks to @Zgarb

```
▼▲‡¦P
```

Takes argents in reverse order and returns `1` for `True` and `0` for `False`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASUA2v9odXNr///ilrzilrLigKHCplD///9bMyw0LDZd/1s2LDEyLDhd)

#### Explanation

```
    P     -- Permutations of the first argument
  ‡       -- Deep zip (vectorises function) with second argument
   ¦      --   Does x divide y
 ▲        -- Get the maximum of that list, returns [1,1...1] if present
▼         -- Get the minimum of that list, will return 0 unless the list is all 1s
```

Comment: `VΠMz¦P` should work for 6 bytes.

Comment: Are those considered "two distinct values"?

Comment: Oh, and `Mz` can be `‡`.

Comment: I think you need `▼▲` instead of `▲▼`. Nice idea in any case!

Answer (score 10):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
Œ!%ḄẠ
```

Returns **0** for *True*, **1** for *False*.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///oJEXVhztaHu5a8P/wciP9yP//o7kUos10FAyNdBQsYnUUoo11FEx0FMxidYDihgY6CqY6CuYgcUMw09DAACJjAmabAlUDNVtCFUARRIURSNAczDYAqzK0BEsbg8SBtkEsMgXZxRULAA)

#### How it works

```
Œ!%ḄẠ  Main link. Arguments: A, B (arrays)

Œ!     Generate all permutations of A.
  %    Take each permutation modulo B (element-wise).
   Ḅ   Convert all resulting arrays from binary to integer.
       This yields 0 iff the permutation is divisible by B.
    Ạ  All; yield 0 if the result contains a 0, 1 otherwise.
```

Answer (score 6):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>8</s> <s>7</s> 6 bytes

*1 byte off using an idea from Dennis' Jelly answer*

```
Y@\!aA
```

Inputs are `B`,  then `A`. Output is `0` if divisible or `1` if not.

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##y00syfmf8D/SIUYx0fG/S8j/aGMdBRMdBbNYrmgzHQVDIx0FCyDTUEfBFMgzMACxDcAcc7AwGIJYJmBpU6BuoDZLoAhY3igWAA)

#### Explanation

```
Y@     % Implicit input: row vector B. Matrix of all permutations, each on a row
\      % Implicit input: row vector A. Modulo, element-wise with broadcast. Gives
       % a matrix in which each row contains the moduli of each permutation of B
       % with respect to A
!a     % True for rows that contain at least a nonzero value
A      % True if all values are true. Implicit display
```

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 7 bytes

Input: takes lists B and A (reversed order)
Output: 1 when true, 0 otherwise

```
œvIyÖPM
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//6OQyz8rD0wJ8//@PNtZRMNFRMIvlijbTUTA00lGwiAUA)

Explanations:

```
œvIyÖPM    Complete program
œ          Pushes all permutations of B as a list
 v         For each permutation
  I        Pushes last input on top of the stack
   yÖ      Computes a % b == 0 for each element of A and B
     P     Pushes the total product of the list
      M    Pushes the largest number on top of the stack
```

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica, 52 bytes

```
Cases[Permutations@#2,p_/;And@@IntegerQ/@(#/p)]!={}&
```

*thanks @ngenisis for -5 bytes*

Comment: `Cases` is generally shorter: `Cases[Permutations@#2,p_/;And@@IntegerQ/@(#/p)]!={}&`

Answer (score 4):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>79</s> <s>74</s> <s>68</s> <s>62</s> 61 bytes

```hs
import Data.List
f a=any((<1).sum.zipWith rem a).permutations
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY4/C8MgEMXn5lPc0CEBEc3fBpqtY/cO4iA0IdJoRM3Qfnlr7NJwHBzv/e7uzcK9xmUJQSqzWg834QW@S@ezCcQg9DvPr7TAblP4I81D@hnsqEAU2IxWbV54uWoXlJAaBniu2clYqT2cYWItAloiuHBWIagRtPzfpQRBg6DjjKaBEnL066Q1cTce6ncs1REqOesOCkk47WMjqDiLAX7fmz0AhC8)

*Saved 1 byte thanks to @nimi*

Comment: 61 bytes: `f a=any((<1).sum.zipWith rem a).permutations`.

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>67</s> 63 bytes

Returns a boolean.

```js
f=([x,...a],b)=>!x||b.some((y,i)=>x%y?0:f(a,c=[...b],c[i]=1/0))
```

#### Test cases

```js
f=([x,...a],b)=>!x||b.some((y,i)=>x%y?0:f(a,c=[...b],c[i]=1/0))

console.log(f([6, 12, 8],[3, 4, 6]))        // true
console.log(f([10, 5, 7],[1, 5, 100]))      // false
console.log(f([14, 10053, 6, 9],[1,1,1,1])) // true
console.log(f([12],[7]))                    // false
```

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/) + [combinat](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/combinat/combinat.pdf), <s>69</s> <s>66</s> 58 bytes

*-3 bytes thanks to Jarko Dubbeldam*

*another -8 bytes thanks to Jarko*

```r
function(a,b)any(combinat::permn(b,function(x)all(!a%%x)))
```

oddly, R doesn't have a builtin for generating all permutations. Returns a boolean.

Additionally, with Jarko's second improvement, `any` coerces the list to a vector of `logical` with a warning.

[Try it online! (r-fiddle)](http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=Os98W9XW&version=3)

Comment: All(x<1) is longer than any(!x) and you should be able to replace sum with any

Comment: @JarkoDubbeldam good call. thank you.

Comment: Oh, and you can omit unlist, yay for implicit coercion.

Comment: @JarkoDubbeldam excellent.

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, 42 bytes

```
MemberQ[Permutations@#2,a_/;And@@(a∣#)]&
```

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 191 bytes

```c
#define F(v)for(i=0;i<v;++i){
#define X if(f(s,n,a,b))return 1
j;f(s,n,a,b,i)int*a,*b;{if(--n){F(n)X;j=i*(n%2);b[j]^=b[n];b[n]^=b[j];b[j]^=b[n];}X;}else{F(s)if(a[i]%b[i])return 0;}return 1;}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZLbasMwDIbv8xQio2CnLsuxXeeF3fUZCiWDuHOGQ@eOJO3FQp4903JoXWhoCMLol/V/Et4vvvb7tn36lJnSEjbkTLNjQVTscvV25vO5orU1qltQGclIyTRLmaC0kNWp0OBZOb9kmaJKV07KHMFrLF8sNK03RNMtz2PlED3zKRe7PPmIxU4n/D/8H/PEzDZb3shDKfFmSbFLulPJTGAYPV3ejO68adrvVGlCrdoC/NAfUm@XQAz1koHnM3hp@EUSgxQwCBksDeUgNQql@pXHDDvA83h2Uq@v@jlVJYGMYCWDLqQew44U3sGuipO04RXsLEV0Gyi3rjx@b@q5DCIGK5NnlDrFc91Bu6XxTRp/kgZnFf5jmmCwDDvDCFeBi1qbUMEFavjvUgUmVTBJhf1F8JgqHDx9E2RIru76h6Z/OOmPY4rwsX/UW7ndNrx1N3dgsgwFuOT@8UTX93PLFZlc0SQX3hfRFFfT/gE)

**Usage:** `f(int size, int size, int *a, int *b)`

returns `1` if divisable, `0` otherwise. See example usage on TIO.

(Gotta do permutations the hard way in C, so this is hardly competitive)

Comment: Suggest `b[j=n%2*i]^=b[n];` instead of `j=i*(n%2);b[j]^=b[n]`

Answer (score 3):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 6 bytes

```
pᵐz%ᵛ0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pf/ahtw6Ompkcdy5VKikpTlfRqQMy0xJziVKXa04vK/xc83DqhSvXh1tkG//9HR0eb6Rga6VjE6kQb65jomMUCGdGGBjqmOuZAliGQNjQwgAiagJimxjpmOpZgKTCESBkBSXMw0wAobWgJlDEG8ox0QGaagkyNBQA)

The predicate succeeds if the two lists are potentially divisible and fails if they are not.

```
pᵐ        For some pair of permutations of the two input lists,
  z       for each pair of corresponding elements
   %ᵛ0    the first mod the second is always zero.
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 bytes

```
Œ!ọẠ€1e
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASwA0/9qZWxsef//xZIh4buN4bqg4oKsMWX///9bNiwgMTIsIDhd/1szLCA0LCA2XQ)

Factorial complexity in the length of the list.

Comment: Does Jelly really not have an `any` builtin? TIL

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth - 11 bytes

```
sm!s%Vdvz.p
```

[Test Suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=sm%21s%25Vdvz.p&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B6%2C+12%2C+8%5D%0A%5B3%2C+4%2C+6%5D%0A%5B10%2C+12%2C+6%2C+5%2C+21%2C+25%5D%0A%5B2%2C+7%2C+5%2C+3%2C+12%2C+3%5D&debug=0&input_size=2).

Comment: You beat me to it :((( - Was just about to post something similar

Answer (score 2):

## CJam, <s>20</s> 17 bytes

```
:A;e!{A\.%:+!}#W>
```

[Test Version](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=l~%3Ail~%3Ai%5C%7B%3AA%3Be!%7BA%5C.%25%3A%2B!%7D%23W%3E%7D~&input=%5B14%2010053%206%209%5D%0A%5B1%201%201%201%5D%0A)

Function that takes array B as the first argument and array A as the second argument. Note that in the test version I switch the order to A then B.

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, <s>112 180</s> 178 bytes

I was thinking too short.

```php
function($a,$b){for($p=array_keys($b);++$i<count($b);){foreach($b as$k=>$x)$f|=$a[$k]%$x;if($f=!$f)return 1;$p[$i]?[$b[$j],$b[$i],$i]=[$b[$i],$b[$j=$i%2*--$p[$i]],0]:$p[$i]=$i;}}
```

anonymous function takes two arrays, returns `NULL` for falsy and `1` for truthy.
Throws an error if second array contains `0`.

[Try it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/00157e5748c09e70b7f1128bf8238538f7f84ac2).

Comment: Prints the wrong result for `$f([6,5],[3,5])`.

Comment: @nwellnhof fixed. thanks for noticing.

Answer (score 2):

## J, 27 bytes

```
0=[:*/(A.~i.@!@#)@]+/@:|"1[
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P03BVk/BwDbaSktfw1GvLlPPQdFBWdMhVlvfwapGyTCay89JTyGkqDSVKzU5I19Bw0zB0EjBQlMhTUHDWMFEwUwTrMAtMacYpsLQQMFUwRyswhDIMjQw0Pz/HwA)

Takes the first list as the left argument and the second list as the right.

Comment: 21 bytes ``(|"1~e.~0*[)i.@!@#A.]``

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (ES6), 100 bytes

```
f=(a,b)=>!a[0]||a.some((c,i)=>b.some((d,j)=>c%d<1&f(e=[...a],d=[...b],e.splice(i,1),d.splice(j,1))))
```

Somewhat inefficient; an extra `&` would speed it up.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 90 bytes

```python
lambda a,b:any(sum(map(int.__mod__,a,p))<1for p in permutations(b))
from itertools import*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LU5dC4JAEHzvV8xbZ2ziWWlJ9UdM5KSkA@@D83oI8bfbXQjL7Aw7s4z9@rfR@dLfHssgVPcUENRVQn/Z@FFMCcuk9mnbKvNsWxJkk@TKe@NgITXsy6mPF14aPbIuSTa9MwrSv5w3ZhghlTXO75YYCH9jpK4LAs8J54ZQHwhHQtFEXvOMcCKUUfA/5Vm2no5/cQr@EL@sjnVWSx5X2TTVBrAu1MZ2mgnTjP094DYNLZTwLBShPmLou/wA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 38 bytes

Actually @nwellnhof's answer seems to be too much readable, so I set out to follow the fine Perl tradition of write-only code :—).

1 byte saved thanks to @nwellnhof.

```perl6
{min max (@^a,) XZ%% @^b.permutations}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY7RCoJAEEXf@4oLJRgsoWVWROA/9BJFwlZrDrm7su5iEn27peFDzMtwz5nhlsIUcSsbTDLs2pckBcmf8JOUsykOR89Dkl5mpTDSWW5Jq@rdVrzz/VPMEM4Z1meG04IhYojP0@1owGHAsGRYdTjs1zAI/oSoj5bf2@@rzc/r58@ad2A1RErXW4yx12i0w5V3hR8C2lnUuVCwuUBp9N1wiYwUVbm4gTIYpxSpO8hCusJSWQhYkqKatR8)

What does it do: It's an anonymous function that takes two list arguments. When we say `@^a`, we mean the first one, when `@^b`, it's the second one.

`(@^a,)` is a list containing the list `@^a`. `@^b.permutations` is the list of all the permutations of `@^b`. The "XZ%%" operator makes all possible pairs of that one list on the left and all the permutations on the right, and uses the operator "Z%%" on them, which is the standard "zip" operation using the divisibility operator %%.

The `max` operator gives the largest element of the list (in this case, it's the list that has the most `True`'s in it). We then reduce it using the logical AND operator to see if all elements of that "most true" list are true, and that's the result. It's nearly exact copy of what @nwellnhof wrote, just using obscure operators to shave off bytes.

Comment: It says `permutations`, it is clearly far too readable ;)

Comment: Well, Perl 6 has a really powerful introspection model. Perhaps I could study it in order to obscure that call? :D

Comment: Replace `[&&]` with `min` to save another byte.

Comment: You can remove the spaces around the `XZ%%`

Comment: I wish something like [`{all (@^a,)Z%%@^b.permutations.any}`](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJKmYPu/OjEnR0HDIS5RRzNKVdUhLkmvILUot7QksSQzP69YLzGvsvZ/cSJIsUa0mY6CoZGOgkWsjkK0sY6CiY6CWaymNRdM2tBAR8FUR8EcJG0IZhoaGKAoMAELmQL1Ao2yhKgDQxRVRiAJc6DQfwA) were possible

Answer (score 2):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `math.combinatorics math.unicode`, 49 bytes

```factor
[ <permutations> [ v/ [ ratio? ] ∄ ] with ∃ ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVC7jsIwEOzzFXM/AEl4Ho/QgWiu4a5CFL5ghAWxI9sBnVAqKPhOfiRsYjiBYEda7axnRtauWGyVLn5m069JDwmz61qskl8hGa1FbNwqkyJWS@7IjpcW94IN15JvkWpu7V@qhbRgxigy9j3v4IHqQGgjCNFFTmMDTaI54V4fGEb41hn/lwc@WuhU8oCmwPcfDJV8zLbmQd8sNa0GBX/eXA6l6018WIk6T7/Aa3zuFXMMUq6TzDIrlDQR5tjVqemSj7DA5Xyivhd0i8v5iEWxcgeIEpaiVlwB)

- `<permutations> [ ... ] with ∃` Is there any permutation of the second input where...
- `v/` ...the quotient of the first input and the permutation...
- `[ ratio? ] ∄` ...contains no ratios? (In other words, are they all integers?)

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 7 bytes

```
Ṗ$vḊvAa
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJBIiwiIiwi4bmWJHbhuIp2QWEiLCIiLCJbNiwgMTIsIDhdLCBbMywgNCwgNl1cblsxMCwgNSwgN10sIFsxLCA1LCAxMDBdXG5bMTQsIDEwMDUzLCA2LCA5XSwgWzEsMSwxLDFdXG5bMTJdLCBbN10iXQ==)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 92 bytes

```python
lambda a,b:any(all(x%y<1for x,y in zip(a,p))for p in permutations(b))
from itertools import*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY3LDoIwEEXX8hWzMbRmFhR5KBGX/ASyKIHGJtA2pSbgzyNFMpuZc@7NmMW9tYpXUb7WgY9tx4FjW3C1ED4MZD4vDya0hRkXkAq@0hCOhlLPjCemt@PHcSe1mkhLaSCsHkG63jqthwnkaLR1l7XrBVRbt6VFcDJWKucfYVg@QxQ7D4KK1BkCixFuDUJ9RUgQsoZ6wSKEFCH3gu0ri6JDJfuRbvmtfv8n9jl87FHe0PUH)

Yer basic implementation.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt/), <s>12</s> 11 bytes

Outputs `true` or `false`.

```
Vá de@gY vX
```

[Test it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=VuEgZGVAZ1kgdlg=&input=WzYsMTIsOF0KWzMsNCw2XQ==)

---

### Explanation

Implicit input of arrays `U` & `V` (`A` & `B`, respectively)

```
Vá
```

Generate an array of all permutations of `V`.

```
d
```

Check if any of the elements (sub-arrays) return true.

```
e@
```

Check if every element in the current sub-array returns true when passed through the following function, with `X` being the current element and `Y` the current index.

```
gY
```

Get the element in `U` at index `Y`.

```
vX
```

Check if it's divisible by `X`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 56 bytes

```ruby
->x,y{x.permutation.any?{|p|p.zip(y).all?{|a,b|a%b==0}}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY5BC4JAEIXv/YqBCAqmZbdS87B26xd0Mw9rrSDotqgLbupvt02jLjEMDPO@93iVSe2YAb@O26hF27VEy6o0jWjyhyJC2VPX616TZ67XdkNEUbiHwLQXq5RzOgzDqCEj69hHYDuEY4IQ7xEOCH6ygSWP4FIZuZghRhE8hOANselklH6wsyjqL3eYFM8Fudxwxqf5k7l7y8GfFDq5WegWYZ9g7PrN1bxfO6PuMsuVvOPshVxBaeEmajm@AA)

Fairly straightforward, exploits the fact that `permutation` exists.

Answer (score 1):

## Scala, 60 Bytes

**Golfed:**

```
a=>b=>b.permutations exists(a zip _ forall(p=>p._1%p._2==0))
```

**Ungolfed:**

```
a=>b=>         // Function literal taking 2 lists of integers, a and b.
b.permutations // All permutations of b.
exists(        // Whether the given function is true for any element.
a zip _        // Zips a and the current permutation of b into a list of pairs.
forall(        // Whether the given function is true for all elements.
p=>            // Function literal taking a pair of integers.
p._1%p._2==0)) // If the remainder of integer division between the members of the pair is 0.
```